# SVN Update problem in Eclipse

Tags: svn, eclipse-plugin

I have been using SVN with Eclipse for ages without problems. But suddenly, one project is not working properly, even though others are fine.

When I try to update I get this:

[image]

In the Eclipse log I see:
    U

> nsupported working copy format svn:
>   This client is too old to work with
>   working copy
>   'C:\Work\xxxxxxxxxxxx\client'; please
>   get a newer Subversion client

Any ideas? I can't see how to update the SVN plugin even if it is too old...

Answer (score 3):

At some point, someone ran a SVN comment on your sandbox using a client that uses a newer fromat than your plugin (probably a Subversion 1.5 client where you had previously been using 1.4).

If you don't update your client/plugin, you can checkout your sandbox again using your preferred client/plugin, or use the change-svn-wc-format.py script, as detailed in the Subversion 1.5 release notes, under [Working Copy and Repository Format Changes](http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.5_releasenotes.html#wc-and-repos-format-change).

Comment: The python script fixed this issue for me.  Except my problem was caused by mixing Tortoise and command-line SVN.

Answer (score 2):

Subversion clients automatically upgrade your working copy when they touch it. As Blair said something has touched your working copy with probably a 1.5 client.

You need to keep all your different Subversion clients - CollabNet (command-line), TortoiseSVN, Subclipse, Subversive, etc. - all on the same minor version (1.4 vs. 1.5), or you'll continue to have this problem.

Blair's got a good strategy for a fix, but the easiest thing to do would be to re-checkout the working copy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set SVN plugin (subclipse?) to use svnkit instead of native client.

Answer (score 0):

If subversion is not included in your SVN plugin, then you need to upgrade your svn client itself.  Have you checked whether the server you're connecting with has not been updated?